# Is there a way to return multiple values with the same drop-down list?

Tags: excel, list, vlookup, multiple-variable-return

I have been tinkering with Excel to explore what it has to offer outside of what I was taught in school. I am working on an efficiency project and I am unsure if this is even possible. I would like to return multiple values in the same cell on different lines using the same drop-down list.

I have attempted several different methods of creating drop-down lists. However, I cannot find in my research any sort of method to accomplish my task.

Unfortunately, I do not have a starting point in terms of a VBA if that is needed.

I ultimately want to use one drop-down list to populate a single cell with multiple values on separate lines.

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/?

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you have a guide for Google Sheets?

Comment: I just searched for `multi-select drop down excel` so try that

Comment: Thank you. The following link shows how to get it done. However, do you happen to know how I could change the code from comma-separated to line-separated? https://support.google.com/docs/thread/1993362?hl=en